# Displaying comments when user is logged out using The_Comments gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise to create users who can comment. Everything works fine when he is signed in. But when a guest user (not logged in) tries to access the page, the comments are not being displayed. I tried to render "_comment.html.erb" directly, but that is throwing an error.

Basically, when the user is not signed in, he should be able to view the comments. When he is signed in, he should be able to make a new comment.

Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: You can mention the actions in the controller . Like an authenticate_user filter , except [show ]

Comment: If you are using authorization, you should probably look at the way you have granted access to guest user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise will create some helpers to use inside your controllers and views. To set up a controller with user authentication, just add this before_action (assuming your devise model is `User`):

```
before_action :authenticate_user! # Which will ask for authenticate user to login
```

So you can write in your comments's controller like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show] # which will applied authentication except defined action

.....
.....
end
```

For [more details](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) you can watch very nicely explained in **[Customizing Devise RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?view=comments)** by Ryan Bates

And in your `show.html.erb` page you can put condition like if user logged in then new comment's form should be appear like

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= render "comments/form" %> # new comment's form
<% end %>
```